# How to authenticate the post using curl?

Tags: php, curl

I have two sites one is a.com another is b.com i am passing data using curl from a.com to b.com ,i am successfully able to pass data but the problem is i want to make it more secure so that site b.com responses after ensuring  that the post was from site a.com.How to obtain this?

Code in site a.com

```
<?php
  $some_data = array(
    'message' =--> 'Hello World',
    'name' => 'Chad'
  ); 

  $curl = curl_init();
  // You can also set the URL you want to communicate with by doing this:
  // $curl = curl_init('http://localhost/echoservice');

  // We POST the data
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  // Set the url path we want to call
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/b.com'); 
  // Make it so the data coming back is put into a string
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  // Insert the data
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $some_data);

  // You can also bunch the above commands into an array if you choose using: curl_setopt_array

  // Send the request
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  // Free up the resources $curl is using
  curl_close($curl);

  echo $result;
?>
```

Code in B.com

```
//I want to check here that the request was from a.com ,if it is ensured then i want to do //the rest of the work
  echo 'Your message was: ' . $_REQUEST["message"] . ' and your name is: ' . $_REQUEST["name"];
?
```

Comment: use SSL, then you can validate the certs on both ends.

Comment: Creating a hashed value (random string) that both sites know would also help with security.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the `$_SERVER['REFERER']` property, but it's very unreliable / unsafe.

A better approach would be to set up the B site with Basic Auth, or something similar, that you can authenticate against when you make the request from site A. Then you can add basic auth to your curl request from A to B. B checks the authentication, and if correct proceeds with the rest of the processing.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`  would  be the solution

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=="IP OF A.com"){

//exec code
}else{
log_error($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] has tried to access B.com at date());//that's an ex .
}
```

Comment: In a simple situation it could work. However it can get very complicated when you start adding multiple servers on any side, adding a proxy or load balancer here and there etc. A token based authentication could be more flexible and easier to scale.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achive this, would be to create a Key that site `a.com` know and site `b.com` knows.

Then you could pass the key from one server to the other via curl, and as long as know one else knows what the key is they won't be able to access it (assuming you program it that way).

This is how most API's work, such as Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin, etc.

Your post data would then look like this for example (`a.com`):

```
$some_data = array(
    'message' =--> 'Hello World',
    'name' => 'Chad',
    'key' => '4h9rj8wj49tj0wgj0ejwrkw0jt0ekv0ijspxodxk9rje0rg9tskvep9rrgt9wkrgte'
);
```

Then on `b.com` you would just do this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['key']) && $_POST['key'] != '4h9rj8wj49tj0wgj0ejwrkw0jt0ekv0ijspxodxk9rje0rg9tskvep9rrgt9wkrgte'){
    die("Invalid Key");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a public/private pair system. A simple version would be like this:

```
//a.com

$keys  = array(
   'publicKey1' => 'privateKey1',
   'publicKey2' => 'privateKey2',
    //...
   'ksjdlfksjdlf' => '989384kjd90903@kjskdjdsd'
);
$publicKeys = array_keys($keys);
//get a random key from pool
$publicKey  = $publicKeys[rand(0, count($publicKeys))];
$privateKey = $keys[$publicKey];

//your data...
$some_data = array(
   'message' => 'Hello World',
   'name' => 'Chad'
);     

/*generate a verification code from data...*/
//add public key to data
$some_data['key'] = $publicKey;
//sort data (to always generate same verification code regardless of params order)
uksort($some_data);

//generate code with your private key
$verificationKey = sha1($privateKey . http_build_query($some_data) . $privateKey);

//add verification code to sent data
$some_data['verification_code'] = $verificationKey;

//send data
curl_exec(...);
```

and on b.com:

```
$keys = "same keys that exist on a.com";
if (!isset($_POST['key']) || !isset($_POST['verification_code']) || !isset($keys[$_POST['key'])) {
    //do something to handle invalid request
}

$verificationKey  = $_POST['verification_code'];    
$privateKey       = $keys[$_POST['key']];

//remove verification code from data
unset($_POST['verification_code']);
//sort data
uksort($_POST);

$checkKey = sha1($privateKey . http_build_query($_POST) . $privateKey);

//validate key
if ($checkKey != $verificationKey) {
   //handle invalid data
}

//verified. do something with $_POST
```